# ¿Cómo elimino la columna que enumera las filas en un dataframe de Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Alguien sabe decirme cómo eliminar la columna que inserta de manera automática Pandas en sus DataFrames?

Me refiero a esta que marco con la fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado creando un sub-DataFrame, pero nada, utilizando set_index, reset_index, en fin, creo que todas las posibilidades que encontré por internet y me sugirió chatGPT, pero ninguna de ellas me elimina esa columna.

Mi objetivo es volcar el contenido de un dataframe a un archivo pero prescindiendo de esa columna. Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, `chatGPT` da respuestas incorrectas de programación el 95% de las veces, mejor hubieras revisado la documentación. Normalmente los métodos para enviar el `dataframe` a archivos tienen el argumento `index` y solo le asignas `False`.

Comment: Quizá me expliqué mal. La documentación está bastante revisada, aunque no descarto que se me hubiera pasado algo. Soy consciente de que chatGPT la caga en programación el 99.9% de las veces (tú has sido muy genereso :D), pero estoy usando la librería tabulate para convertir el dataframe en una tabla de texto perfectamente formateada (una especie de informe). Así me ha sido imposible eliminar esa columna. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato como sabes que chatGPT da respuestas incorrectas?

Comment: @JoséManuel, la primera columna se llama índice, no se puede eliminar totalmente ya que el `dataframe` necesita tener una referencia para las filas, lo que puedes hacer es convertir tu columna `id` a índice.

Comment: @RolyQ. en mi trabajo frecuentemente tengo que explorar y probar nuevos IDE's, lenguajes de programación, IA, etc... por ahora el nivel de programación de `chatGPT` no es bueno, no sé si sea la falta de entendimiento del problema o si el modelo con el que la entrenaron no tenía suficiente información. Si le preguntas cosas de librerías muy específicas por lo general te devuelve código no funcional o que ha sido depreciado ya que al no estar conectada a internet no está al pendiente de modificaciones en nuevas versiones.

Comment: OK, está claro. Era lo que suponía tras no encontrar nada por internet. A alguien le tenía que haber surgido la misma duda que a mí, y ni en la versión en inglés de este sitio encontré algo. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Esa columna extra es el index que requiere pandas para operar, por lo visto usas una columna "id" que coincide perfectamente con dicha funcionalidad. Si esa columna no tiene valores repetidos, puede representar el ID que pandas requiere por defecto.
Suelo realizar varios procesos y al final asignar la columna id a la columna que necesite pero al abrir un archivo con pandas también la podes definir, fijate cuál te conviene más.